# Redirect / route s3 bucket to domain

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3, routes

Hi I am looking for the best way to redirect  / route all s3 bucket links to a domain or link domain to s3 bucket.

I am migrating from dedicated hosting to aws and using s3 bucket to store files.

Example: http://www.example.com.au/app --> directs to http://examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/app

But i have heaps of them and hybrid apps that point to domain/files so not sure if theres a way to route within aws console or php script to achieve?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can **point a custom domain name to an Amazon S3 bucket**, if the bucket is named the same as the domain name.

So, if you own the domain name `example.com`, you can point `www.example.com` to a bucket called `www.example.com` with these steps:

- Create the bucket with the matching name
- Turn on Static Website hosting and copy the displayed URL
- Create a Route 53 Record Set for `www.example.com` point it to the URL copied earlier

See documentation: [Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

**Update:** As pointed out by sqlbot, another option is to use Amazon CloudFront in front of Amazon S3. This has several benefits:

- The bucket name does not need to match the domain name
- The domain name can point to several different origins (eg `/images` could come from one bucket and `/css` could come from another)
- It supports `HTTPS` (which is not possible when going direct to Amazon S3 because the URL resolves to a generic S3 IP address)

Comment: You stopped typing before you got to the part about "if the bucket already exists and the bucket name doesn't match the desired hostname, or if you need to support HTTPS, then CloudFront..."

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I am getting my IT team to review these options. Will come back with a status shortly.